# Union rasters previously cut by bounding box

Tags: postgis, raster

**How do I union rasters, where the original data is grouped by an attribute without running into an issue where the rasters that should be unioned, aren't the same sizes?**

I'm trying to generate a single PNG for the users' current bounding box. 
Cutting the required geometries works great and I end up with a few clipped geoms that match the bounding box exactly.
The geometries are grouped by an attribute `int` and coloured accordingly.

However after this, I can't seem to get the rasters to join up into a single image.

---

Some detail

*Bounds is drawn in blue*

```sql
--bounds
select 
   st_geomfromtext(
        'POLYGON((18.48287 -33.95910, 18.49523 -33.95910,18.49523 -33.96829,18.48287 -33.96829,18.48287 -33.95910))
       ')
  ) as bounding_box
```

[image: Geometries with bounding box drawn in blue]

*Data*

```sql
--bounds
select data.wkb_geometry, data.attibute
from (
         values ('POLYGON((18.4893249 -33.9693479,18.487338 -33.975303,18.4836563 -33.9722486,18.4810635 -33.9694083,18.4804401 -33.9701518,18.4788584 -33.969387,18.4769812 -33.9711783,18.4758629 -33.9699897,18.47497 -33.96881,18.474341 -33.9686,18.4763888 -33.9636919,18.4771354 -33.9638799,18.4780189 -33.964247,18.4793621 -33.9646786,18.4798761 -33.964869,18.480315 -33.9650772,18.4808655 -33.9654135,18.482002 -33.9662287,18.4893249 -33.9693479))',1),
                ('POLYGON((18.4874775 -33.9753787,18.4895958 -33.9693783,18.4911785 -33.9672392,18.4912114 -33.9667627,18.4911048 -33.9664196,18.4895065 -33.9645728,18.4884931 -33.96334,18.4879777 -33.9624253,18.4876715 -33.9620845,18.4863472 -33.9608744,18.4858276 -33.959958,18.4856109 -33.959617,18.4855713 -33.959227,18.4856073 -33.9587142,18.4859062 -33.9558208,18.4861392 -33.953389,18.4862619 -33.9529841,18.4865074 -33.9523433,18.4870734 -33.9526725,18.4884629 -33.9534733,18.4896968 -33.9542027,18.4909845 -33.955003,18.4919826 -33.95558,18.4933138 -33.9563781,18.4936203 -33.9565488,18.4937229 -33.9567017,18.4938761 -33.9568949,18.4939786 -33.9570856,18.4936162 -33.9585412,18.4932268 -33.9600814,18.4933172 -33.9602339,18.4935444 -33.9602731,18.4937287 -33.9603389,18.4936413 -33.9608175,18.4937095 -33.9615053,18.4948511 -33.9614817,18.4956911 -33.9636467,18.4954551 -33.9660477,18.4944031 -33.9682377,18.4932861 -33.9725157,18.4924889 -33.9766531,18.4911568 -33.9783253,18.4905335 -33.9781892,18.4874775 -33.9753787))',1),
                ('POLYGON((18.478434 -33.959864,18.479759 -33.959663,18.48191 -33.959769,18.485405 -33.959819,18.4860366 -33.9609406,18.487591 -33.962258,18.487962 -33.962984,18.489653 -33.964911,18.4906361 -33.9661385,18.4909099 -33.9666043,18.49098 -33.96699,18.4893785 -33.9692589,18.4857733 -33.9677527,18.4820824 -33.9661842,18.481005 -33.965369,18.4803673 -33.9650016,18.4796866 -33.9647409,18.4764746 -33.9635707,18.476956 -33.962229,18.47781 -33.961372,18.478434 -33.959864))',2)
     ) as data (wkb_geometry, attibute);
```

[image: Vector Polygons coloured]

Now the original polygons are grouped by `attribute` and unioned. 
Generating the PNGs works great however the result is not unioned into a single image. Infact the result is three individual PNGs.

[image]

The result above is missing the green polygon in the previous image, which I need to be included to create a final single PNG with all clipped polygons, regardless of attribute.

*ignoring the fact that the above blue polygon is missing, unintentional when the screenshot was taken*

This is where I run into the issue where if I attempt to `union` the rasters, I get the error

`ST_Union(raster): ERROR: rt_raster_from_two_rasters: The two rasters provided do not have the same alignment`

Ideally I guess would be to create a reference raster (?) as to help keep context of where the geometries should be unioned.

I'm not sure if this is the solution as I can imagine you'd end up with a randomly generating a result where `attribute=1` would overlap `attribute=2` and vice versa, depending on the union order of the geoms.

This is rough. Anyway here is the query.

*Query*

```sql
with bbox as (select st_setsrid( st_geomfromtext(
                           'POLYGON((18.48287 -33.95910,18.49523 -33.95910,18.49523 -33.96829,18.48287 -33.96829,18.48287 -33.95910))'), 4326) as bounding_box
    ), clipped as (
        SELECT ST_union(st_intersection( wkb_geometry,bbox.bounding_box))
                   as wkb_geometry,attribute
        from data_table,
             bbox where st_intersects(wkb_geometry, bbox.bounding_box) group by attribute
    ), rasters as (
    select ST_AsRaster(
                clipped.wkb_geometry,
                256, 256, ARRAY ['8BUI', '8BUI', '8BUI'],
                (CASE
                     WHEN attribute = 1 THEN ARRAY [66,135,245]
                     WHEN attribute = 2 THEN ARRAY [48, 59, 99]
                    --...
                     ELSE ARRAY [147,150,150] END),
                ARRAY [0,0,0]
               ) as rast
    from clipped
)
SELECT ST_AsPNG(rasters.rast) as tile
from rasters;
```

## --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**UPDATE**

Image generation works with the answer from [Pierre Racine] however I'm struggling to generate low quality pngs where the sides aren't cut off (see second image with darker background

[image: example]
[image: example2]

This results in tiles that dont fit their `div` exactly.

[image: div fit]

The only solution for now is generating high resolution images, takes up to 30 sec, which reduces these slivers to mostly unnoticeable. However not ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to align all the rasters created with ST_AsRaster() with additional parameters (scalex, scaley, gridx, gridy) so that you can then ST_Union() them together into a single raster before ST_AsPNG() it.

In the example below I have set both pixel sizes (scalex and scaley) to 0.05 and both pixel alignment (gridx and gridy) to 0 when calling ST_AsRaster(). This correspond to variant 4 of ST_AsRaster() in the doc.

```
WITH bbox AS (
  SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((18.48287 -33.95910,18.49523 
  -33.95910,18.49523 -33.96829,18.48287 -33.96829,18.48287 -33.95910))'), 4326) 
  AS bounding_box
), clipped AS (
  SELECT ST_Union(ST_Intersection(wkb_geometry, bbox.bounding_box)) AS wkb_geometry, 
         attribute
  FROM data_table, bbox 
  WHERE ST_Intersects(wkb_geometry, bbox.bounding_box) 
  GROUP BY attribute
), rasters AS (
  SELECT ST_AsRaster(clipped.wkb_geometry, 0.05, -0.05, 0, 0, 
                     ARRAY['8BUI', '8BUI', '8BUI'], 
                     (CASE WHEN attribute = 1 THEN ARRAY [66, 135, 245] 
                           WHEN attribute = 2 THEN ARRAY[48, 59, 99]
                           --...
                           ELSE ARRAY[147,150,150] END),
                     ARRAY[0,0,0]) AS rast
  FROM clipped
)
SELECT ST_AsPNG(ST_Union(rasters.rast)) as tile
FROM rasters;
```

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: Added... but not tested on any data.

Comment: Thanks for your example, I seems 0.00002 was needed for `scalex` and `scaley`. I'll admit I rolled the dice, not knowing exactly how these impact the end result. The resulting image is flipped on its x-axis though... might be as simple as flipping to `-0.00002`...

Comment: `-0.00002` did the trick. I'll have to implement this in the next few days, the resulting image seems to be slightly projected, which I hope is caused by 4326 projection on a 3857 map. I'll mark this as accepted as this did infact generate the expected PNG.

Comment: Iv'e added an update to the original question if you could take a look at that.